# Emulador en phonegap sin conexión a internet

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, phonegap

Cuando emulo en MacOsx con el Android Studio, mi AVD de android tiene internet sin ningún problema, en cambio cuando emulo através de phonegap:

```
phonegap emulate android
```

o através del tools del sdk de android

```
emulator -avd NEXUS -verbose
```

No tiene conexión a internet.

La APP que estoy utilizando es helloworld la que crear por defecto phonegap.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

En el `config.xml`:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

En `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Y reinstala el [plugin whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist):

```
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
> cordova prepare
```